# How do I make a favicon?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, favicon

[image: This is the logo I'm using and its the PSA part that I'm trying to convert into a favicon.]

I'm trying to make a [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) with the first part of the logo (PSA) for a website I'm building but I'm stumped how? I'm still quite a fledgling when it comes to Photoshop cc and Illustrator cc so any help will be great.

Comment: Hello Dominic, welcome to GD.SE. I don't mean to be rude, but have you googled your question? The term 'how to make a favicon' yields some 8 million results for me. Please review some of those and [edit] your question with specifics if there's any part where you get stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Vincent, sorry about that I should have searched better I'll make sure it wont happen again.

Comment: It's okay, no need to apologise so profusely :) We do ask some research effort in your questions though. Have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to better understand how things work here. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Favicon best practices regarding size and format](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/26946/52050)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Photoshop:

Start with using the crop tool to crop it into a square with just the Circle.
Do not distort it to make it a perfect circle - leave it as an oval, and just have extra space on the sides.
(Make sure to save a copy of the original artwork)

Then use the magic wand selection to remove all the white - make it transparent (If you don't it will end up looking weird on the browser (since most browsers color isn't white)

[image]

Note, it may look better to just leave the white in the inside and transparent the outside - that's up to you.

[image]

Then resize the image to 16x16px or possibly higher [Read more about it on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4014823/9240845).

Save file as png (to preserve transparency - jpg and other formats won't do it)

---

You can then use an online tool to convert your png into a favicon (some of the popular simple website builders will let you just put it in as a png)

<sub>Worth noting, that some website creating tools allow you to just upload a high res png of the favicon and they will do the scaling for you - you just upload the image and the system takes care of the rest.</sub>

Comment: Then read [Favicon best practices regarding size and format](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69969/52050) :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it yourself, especially if you're not sure how to proceed.
To be fully compatible (and hence useful), a favicon has to be created in a variety of formats and size.

I would recommend using an on-line solution / generator like https://realfavicongenerator.net/ , once you cropped your image successfully (using one of the other answers).
Another option would be to follow the (long, inclusive, using Photoshop) tutorial at http://www.emergeinteractive.com/insights/detail/The-Essentials-of-FavIcons-in-2017

I provide more technical details, oriented at webmasters, [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768184/2657549).

Answer (score 3):

Use the crop tool in Photoshop, and set the height and the width as much you need, usually 16x16, 50x50 o 150x150. This will create the crop square
[image]

Drag the image to the right so that the crop square fits on the left
[image]

Crop image and save to PNG
[image]

Done!

Comment: In pixel size, it is (can be) 16x16 etc... but in reality [regarding cropping] it's just a 1x1 ratio, and then resized to a smaller image.